# Mysql Error Occured for table : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Got error 90 "Message too long" during COMMIT

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, galera

I got this error from one of my developer. i Tried to search on web but i didnt find anything. The full error is as follows -

```
Error Occured for table: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Got error 90 "Message too long" during COMMIT at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at AlteryxMigration.clsAlteryxMig.altrxfileUpload(String strConnString, String strFile, String strTableName)
```

we are inserting 25 rows line through load data file.

wsrep_max_ws_size = 2 GB

can anyone suggest me.

Comment: Do the 25 lines have some big text?/blobs?  How big is the gdata file?

Comment: yeah. its a big file with blobs and text. some where around 10 mb